# mongoose pre update hook - update document doesn't work

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

*mongoose v4.4.7*

I'm updating Parking model from a controller of another model.
I want to do a second update before that update, but it doesn't seem to work in the mongoose hook.

Given this query ...

```
// non Parking controller
Parking.update({_id: parked.parkingId}, {
  $set: { 'availability.current': true }
});
```

I want to do something like ...

```
// Parking Model
ParkingsSchema.pre('update', function() {
var self = this;

  if (self._update.$set['availability.current']) {
    var id = self._conditions._id;
    self.findOne()
      .then(doc => {
        self.update({}, {$set:{'availability.until': doc.ownerBackAt}})
      })
      .catch(logger.log);
  }

});
```

The self.update doesn't seem to do anything
I added console.log(this) to the pre update hook and it's not showing.

what am I doing wrong?

maybe It's not possible to query the document in the pre/post update hooks?

Comment: what mongoose version you are using.. update hooks are only supported after 4.x

Comment: @NaeemShaikh mongoose v4.4.7

Answer (score 3):

You forgot next() callback. I have skipped the 'then' way and used normal findOne and update way which should do your job.

Note that if you're going to modify the document or throw an error or something depending on the results of the findOne(), you'll need to move the next() callback inside of the findOne callback.

```
ParkingsSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  var self = this;
  if (self._update.$set.availability.current) {
     var id = self._conditions._id;
     self.findOne({key:id},function(err,doc){
         if(err)
           console.log(err);
         else
           self.update({},{$set:{'availability.until': doc.ownerBackAt}});
     });
  }
  next();
});
```